# How to make a borderless table on pptxgenjs in 2d array slide

Tags: javascript, node.js, pptxgenjs

I am creating a presentation using `pptgenjs` however i can't seems to create a table border as i wants it to be.

here is the data that i'm trying to use:

```
let rows = [
   ["data1","data2"],
   ["data3","data4"],
   ["data5","data6"],
]
```

here is what i tried so far:

```
let arrBorder = [null,null,{color:'DA70D6'},null]
slide.addTable(rows,{rowH:1,border:arrborder})
```

in the method i tried, to make a null on the top, left and right of the table, while the bottom are having a line which resulted in this:

[image]

However what i wanted the following:

[image]

Any advice on how to make it works?

Comment: Their [table documentation](https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/docs/api-tables.html) shows how to specify formatting per cell.

Comment: Thanks for the help, yeah i looked at it before i posted but i'm not sure since its 2d array, will it be the following? data = { text: "Top Lft", options: { align: "left", fontFace: "Arial" } } let rows = [ [ [{data},{data}], [{data},{data}], [{data},{data}], [{data},{data}], ], ];

afterward:

slide.table(rows,{ x: 0.5, y: 3.5, w: 9, h: 1, colW: 1,border:{null,null,'B22222',null})

doesnt seems to work since it gave the whole column a line rather than only one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on their [table documentation](https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/docs/api-tables.html), I believe it goes together like this:

```js
const col2cellstyle = {border: [null, null, {color:'DA70D6'}, null]};
const table = rows.map(row => row.map((value, col) => ({
  text: value,
  options: col == 1 ? col2cellstyle : null;
})));
slide.addTable(table, {rowH: 1});
```

The resulting data structure that's fed into `.addTable` would look like:

```js
[
  [
    {text: "data1", options: null}, 
    {text: "data2", options: {border: [null, null, {color:'DA70D6'}, null]}},
  ],
  [
    {text: "data3", options: null}, 
    {text: "data4", options: {border: [null, null, {color:'DA70D6'}, null]}},
  ],
  [
    {text: "data5", options: null}, 
    {text: "data6", options: {border: [null, null, {color:'DA70D6'}, null]}},
  ],
]
```